# I don't understand this Django template error message

Tags: django, django-templates

Here's the error message populating my page, with the accompanying code issue:

## TemplateSyntaxError at /home

### Invalid block tag: 'endblock', expected 'endif'

Request Method:  GET

Request URL:     http://localhost:8000/home

Django Version:  1.3.1

Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError

Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'endblock', expected 'endif'

Code:

```
{% extends "profile/base_with_classes.html" %}

{% block username %}
    {% if user == None %}
        Nobody
        {% else %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {{ user.username }}
        {% else %}
            Unauthenticated User
        {% endif %}
    (% endif %}
{% endblock username %}    <==== Issue is here
```

I don't understand. This is at the top of the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the last endif, you have `(` instead of `{`

Comment: +1 good catch. This is definitely the problem. The error indicates that `{% endblock %}` is being called before the if statement is closed with `{% endif %}`. Which is the case because the `{% endif %}` is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is not only the problem; `{% endblock %}` tag does not really require the name of the block to close. Try to experiment with various cases when logged in and when not

Comment: it may not require it, but including the name is not a problem, and it certainly makes the file more readable, especially in the case of nested blocks or very long blocks.